# Store row count in database or get dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

Say I have a table full of comments, each from different users, and I want to count how many comments each user has. Should I have a separate table with the count, and update that on creation/deletion of comments, or should I query the count every time?

I feel like the latter is better, but I want some more experienced input on the matter. Thanks.

Comment: I prevaricated in my answer because this is a bit of a subjective question. Both are good solutions, but re-calculating each time has obvious performance implications based on your exact situation. I prefer to store values rather than calculate them, but you might not – databases are fun! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the good old [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principle, I would suggest you go with the simplest solution for now, which is just counting the number of comments as needed. This is just pragmatic coding.

If, down the line, you find this is causing even small performance problems, then you should replace it with a cached value using a stored procedure or similar, but chances are it will serve you just fine.

So, I realise this probably isn't the clear answer you want, but: if you're making something small, go with the easy solution (counting); if you're making something bigger, go with the easy solution (counting) then upgrade to the harder solution (storing a value) if you find you need it. If you know what you're making is guaranteed to be big (lucky you!) then fine, go straight for the harder solution.

Note: I've said "harder solution" but as you probably know it's only fractionally harder than the easy solution.

Comment: This is as clear as an answer I needed
I am going to follow YAGNI for now :)

Answer (score 1):

After a commnent is created or deleted you should count right in the hour.

If you count every time you will make some desnecessary querys.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `MYSQL count` for each user comments would be the easiest way to go about this as below :

```
$userid= ? ;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE userid=userid
```

Updating the table every-time will result to multiple MYSQL calls each time you need to query the comments.

Alternatively you would create a column for comments count in the user , and add the comments for that specific user each time he/she adds a comment , then just querying the user you will have the comments for that user

Comment: Im aware on how to do it, I just didn't know which method to use :P